# Angular mixing normal text with data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding

So I have a template file where if I do this it works

```
<td>{{result.data.test}}</th>
```

but on the very same page, if I try to mix normal text with data binding, it doesn't work

```
<td><a href="#">ABC_{{result.data.test}}.GHI</a></td>
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: (1) AngularJS != Angular. (2) `result` != `$result`.

Comment: There is a `$` sign on your second text `{{$re`

Comment: Sorry I was just trying something. Edited my post. There is no $

Comment: @p0tta: What do you mean by _"it doesn't work"_? What is actually rendered?

Comment: blank text, or rather it shows me ABC_.GHI

Comment: show us what 'result' looks like